# Oneboxes in chat may overlap with timestamps

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

See here:

[image: screenshot of onebox in chat covering up bottom of timestamp]

Comment: Heh, I've noticed this on many occasions and never considered reporting it as a bug, but +1. [I apologize for bumping this post at this particular time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83181/chat-and-blog-and-sede-servers-down), but I just came across it.

Comment: @PopularDemand ~ Is this what you do when the chat servers go down?

Comment: @drachenstern, apparently it is, but do not mistake correlation for causation.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed a while ago; it was a left-over from IE7 days. See [Post times cut off when posting One Box content in chat](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/post-times-cut-off-when-posting-one-box-content-in-chat/1256#1256).