# The timestamp for a message covers the menu for a starred message

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

On chat, I clicked on the arrow to get the menu for a starred message, and its permanent link.

[image: screenshot]

The timestamp for the message shown to the left covers the permanent link.

[image: screenshot]

These are the CSS styles that apply to the timestamp (a `<div>` with the "timestamp" class).

```
.monologue .timestamp {
  color: black;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

If this makes any difference, I am using Google Chrome 24.0.1312.52 on OS X 10.8.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Fixed in the next build.

For web devs, the details on this may be interesting though:

There is a [discussion on the W3C mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012May/0473.html) to make elements that are `position: fixed` create their own stacking context, even if they're `z-index: auto` (usually for an element to create a new stacking context, it needs to be both positioned *and* have a non-auto z-index).

This is only a discussion so far, but there is one (non-mobile) browser that already implements it: Chrome. [More details on html5rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements); [relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798669/chrome-cant-position-one-absolute-div-over-another-when-the-parent-is-fixed).

The chat sidebar is `position: fixed`, but does not have a non-auto z-index. The popup menu is a descendent of the sidebar, and it's `z-index: 50`. The message time stamp is `z-index: 1` (because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57137/oneboxes-in-chat-may-overlap-with-timestamps)).

So until the change appeared in Chrome 22, the sidebar did not create a new stacking context, and thus the popup and the time stamp were in the same stacking context, with the popup appearing on top because of the higher z-index.

In Chrome 22+, where `position: fixed` now implies `z-index: 0`, the sidebar establishes a new stacking context, and because `0 < 1` it is *below* the timestamps. The popup menu is part of this new stacking context, and thus its z-index of 50 doesn't matter anymore – it's still below the time stamp.